# Step functions: Using $-|\phi| \leq \phi \leq |\phi|$ conclude $|\int^b_a \phi(x)dx| \leq \int^b_a|\phi(x)|dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, step-function

Let $\phi :[a,b] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a step function.

Using $-|\phi| \leq \phi \leq |\phi|$ I need to conclude that $|\int^b_a \phi(x)dx| \leq \int^b_a|\phi(x)|dx$

I have no idea how to prove this. I start with :

Let $P$ be a partition $P=\{p_0,...,p_k\}$ on $[a,b]$ such that it is compatible with $\phi$. Let $\phi_i$ be the values that $\phi$ takes on each interval $(p_{i-1}, p_i)$. We know that $-|\phi| $ and $|\phi|$ are step functions, so we can see that $-|\phi_i| \leq \phi_i \leq |\phi_i|$ for all $1 \leq i \leq k$. Then

$$-|\phi_i| \leq \phi_i \leq |\phi_i|\text{ \\ $ \times (p_i-p_{i-1})$}$$

$$\Rightarrow -|\phi_i|(p_i-p_{i-1}) \leq \phi_i(p_i-p_{i-1}) \leq |\phi|(p_i-p_{i-1}) \text{\\ $\times \sum^k_{i=1}$}$$

$$\Rightarrow \sum^k_{i=1}-|\phi_i|(p_i-p_{i-1}) \leq \sum^k_{i=1}\phi_i(p_i-p_{i-1}) \leq \sum^k_{i=1}|\phi_i|(p_i-p_{i-1})$$

$$\Rightarrow \int^b_a -|\phi|(x)dx \leq \int^b_a\phi(x)dx \leq \int^b_a|\phi|(x)dx$$

And this is where I get stuck. I think I'm not doing the correct thing. If anyone could help me identify what i'm doing wrong, that would be great. Or just hint me how to start my proof.

Comment: Multiply the first inequality with $-1$. What do the two inequalities tell you then?

Comment: @Thorgott i'm not sure what to do after multiplying by $-1$. As in I don't see anything with which I can continue with

Comment: One inequality gives $\int_a^b\phi\le\int_a^b|\phi|$, the other gives $-\int_a^b\phi\le\int_a^b|\phi|$. Now recall the definition of absolute value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
-|\varphi |\leq \varphi \leq |\varphi |&\implies -\int |\varphi |\leq \int \varphi \leq \int|\varphi |\\
&\implies \left|\int \varphi \right|\leq \left|\int |\varphi |\right|=\int|\varphi |.
\end{align*}

Comment: why is $\left|\int |\varphi |\right|=\int|\varphi |$? Could you please expand you answer, as some parts are not clear for me

Comment: because $\int|\varphi |\geq 0$. @Mavzouleus

Comment: as in if $a \geq 0$  and $a \leq |a|$ then $|a| = | |a| |$?

Comment: if $a\geq 0$, then $|a|=a$.